# Hybris FlexibleSearch Approved Products

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

I wanted to only search the approved products in a certain catalog.
**Product name: Product_Db**
`approvalStatus = approved`
`catalog = prodCatalog`

How to make the query?

Answer (score 4):

You can test your flex query in hac Console > FlexibleSearch tab. You can use below flex query for approval status and catalog.

```
select * from {product 
          join catalog on {product:catalog} = {catalog:pk} 
          join ArticleApprovalStatus on {product:approvalstatus} = {ArticleApprovalStatus:pk}}
where {catalog:id} = 'apparelProductCatalog' 
  and {ArticleApprovalStatus:code} = 'approved'
```

Comment: How to get products online only?

Comment: You can use {catalog:version} for this in WHERE clause.

Comment: where {catalog:id} = 'apparelProductCatalog' and {ArticleApprovalStatus:code} = 'approved' and {catalog:version} = 'Online'

Comment: Can you check {catalog:version} is string, may me it is enum.

Comment: select {catalog:version} from {catalog} Not works for me.

Comment: You can use {product:catalogVersion} = {catalog:activeCatalogVersion}